# To remove a challenging-named file by Git rm

Tags: git

The name of the file is "\033[A.tex".
Note that the filename includes two times the character ".

I run unsuccessfully

```
git rm ""\033[A.tex""
```

and

```
git rm "\033[A.tex"
```

**How can you remove the file from Git?**

[edit]

The filename is more challenging.

**Situation**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/git-rm.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/git-rm.png)

Comment: Is it actually called "\033[A.tex" or is its second character, octal 033 aka hex 1b aka ESC?

Comment: You got it. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does any of the following work?

```
git rm "\\033[A.tex"
git rm "\*A.tex" (assuming this pattern matches no other files)
git rm "*A.tex" (same assumption)
```

Comment: This command works: git rm "\*A.tex" (assuming this pattern matches no other files).

Comment: If somebody knows a more secure solution, please add a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes should help:

```
git rm '"\\033\[A.tex"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git rm "./\033[A.tex"
```

That will look in your current directory.

Or try typing ./\033 then pressing tab to autocomplete in some shells.

Answer (score 0):

It will work this way for sure.

```
git rm \\033\[A.tex
```

No assumption needed. There is a pattern followed to identify such challenging names(can't find where its documented). But this will work.

**EDIT**

For more chalenging name

```
git rm "\"\\033[A.tex\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
git rm \"\\033\[A.tex\"
```

Comment: I worked on a local git repo, so works here. What OS/shell are you running?

Comment: I use OS X Leopard, Git 1.6.3.3. - Please, see my edit in my question: the filename is more challenging than I first thought.